# how to display data from database without using datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to show all data from database in C# without using `DataGridView`? Is there any way to do this in a nice table layout like in ASP? I took this screenshot of a `DataGridView` but it looks terrible.

[image: Poorly-looking DataGridView.]

Comment: In Winforms you are pretty limited... You can use a `ListView` but with many columns it could get messy.  Otherwise you are stuck with `DataGridView` or a third party control like Telerik's GridView.

Comment: Evan how about Telerik GridView i hared this in asp but not in C# does it really possible with C# ?
and how to do this ? there any useful link ?

Comment: you can try dev express controls, they are more interactive than windows forms controls

Comment: AFAIK DGV don't have rowspan or colspan. Other than that they are very flexible and can be configured to look pretty good.

What do you mean 'the image blew'? That you don't like it? Define your layout wishes and we'll see if they're possible..

Comment: TaW yeah this image so awful I don't like this style am really search for nice style

Comment: @ShanazK C# is a language - ASP.Net is a framework and WinForms is a framework.  Both are written in C# (or VB.Net).  Telerik has some WinForms controls too.  Not sure what they're called.  Dev Express controls look nice too.

Comment: You might look at wpf, you can style it however you like [examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples)